# Seeking an intuitive proof that the divisor function $d$ has $d(n) = o(n^\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

It is clear that the number of divisors, d(n) grows alot more slowly than the number line, hence it is intuitive that >0, d(n)=o(n^)

But is there an intuitive way to formulate the proof? We can translate it into a simple-sounding problem:

Suppose we have a group of drummers playing different beats. 
The first drummer sets the beat//
The second drummer hits his drum every second beat of the first drummer//
The third hits every third beat//
etc

Now the question is simply: what is the rate at which the drummers' beats coincide increases, relative to the beat set by the first drummer?

This is the same as the divisor function. On the 6th beat the first second and third and sixth drummers play together. On the 12th beat the first, second third fourth sixth and twelfth players hit their drums at the same time.

Obviously, the rate at which the number of drum beats coincide increases a lot more slowly than the number of beats the first drummer has played. But how much more slowly?

Comment: It does require a proof. Once that is done, Ramanujan pointed out that, for any real $\delta > 0,$ there is a maximal value of $\frac{d(n)}{n^\delta}.$ When, for example, $\delta $ is rational, the maximum is attained at just a single value of $n.$ Such an $n$ is called a Superior Highly Composite Number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superior_highly_composite_number

Comment: Your problem is in Hardy and Wright, theorem 315 (page 260 in edition 5) and proved in half a page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to make your intuition more quantitative. Imagine the drummers have been playing for a long time, which you estimate is around $n$ beats, and you're about to start listening. How many drummers will hit the first beat you hear? Drummer 1 will definitely hit it. Drummer 2 hits half of all the beats, drummer 3 hits a third of them, and so on, up through drummer $n$, and the later drummers haven't begun playing. So the average number of hits per beat that we'll hear over the next few beats is approximately $\frac 1 1 + \frac 1 2 + ... + \frac 1 n$, which is approximately $\log n$ (see [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence)) and grows more slowly than any positive power of $n$.

This idea doesn't yield a proof of the statement you mentioned, though, because the divisor function can exceed this "local average", and the argument above doesn't help us bound that behavior.

Comment: Thanks Karl! When you say 'more slowly' than any positive power of n (or also n) is there a clear way to say how much more slowly? is it d(n) ≈log  ?

Comment: Yeah, the slow growth of $\log n$ is what I was referring to: for every $\epsilon>0$, for sufficiently large $n$, $n^\epsilon>\log n$. $\log n$ is not an upper bound on $d(n)$, but it's its "expected value" or "average value near $n$" in an informal sense (that can be made precise).

Answer (score 2):

It follows from $$\pi(2k)\log 2k\ge \sum_{p\le 2k}\log p= \sum_{p^m\le 2k}\log p+O(k^{1/2}) \\\ge \sum_{p^m\le 2k}\log p \lfloor 2k/p^m\rfloor = \log {2k\choose k} +O(k^{1/2})\ge O(k)$$ that $$n\le e^{rk} \implies \sum_{p| n} 1\le C\frac{\log n}{\log \log n} \implies d(n)\le 2^{C\frac{\log n}{\log \log n}}=n^{c/\log\log n}=O(n^\epsilon)$$

Comment: Thank you @reuns. If I can be honest, I don't think this is an "intuitive" proof, since it is more of a black box (it's very hard for me as a non-professional mathematician to understand this). I'm hoping for something that could be explained to a 12 year old... :  )

Comment: Proofs aside, the result you're asking for, that $d(n)$ is $o(n^\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon>0$, is somewhat technical in itself. I'm not sure how I'd even explain raising a number to a power between 0 and 1 to a twelve-year-old.

Comment: Thanks Karl - the reason I translated the problem into a very easy-to-understand analogy (which is a perfect analogy) is that I feel like the rate of change of the increase in 'number of beats that coincide' must surely have an easier explanation than the ones currently available.

Comment: Ah yeah, there are certainly intuitive arguments that shed some light on the growth rate of $d(n)$ without fully proving the theorem you mentioned. For example, the *average* value of $d$ over the numbers $1,...,n$ is $\frac 1 1+\frac 1 2+...+\frac 1 n\approx\log n$.

Comment: ok! Can I ask you for a proof/explanation of that? (again, suppose I'm 12...)