# $\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{d_n}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, real-numbers, prime-factorization

**Question**

$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{d_n}{n}$, where $d_n$ is the number of divisors of $n$

**Draft**
I think it doesn't exist

Another somewhat related question, in factoring a number into prime factors, say $n=p_1^{k_1} p_2^{k_2} \cdots p_m^{k_m}$, we can say that $k_i \in \{0,1, 2, \cdots, n\}$?

Comment: There are two subsequences of the natural numbers, $\{p_n\}$, the prime numbers, and $\{2^n\}$, which you can focus on.

Comment: Thanks, i'm think some like that

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562744/seeking-an-intuitive-proof-that-the-divisor-function-d-has-dn-on-epsilo

Comment: Never mind, I thought wrong—my comment doesn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. Note that $d_n\leq 2\sqrt{n}$: if $a$ is a positive divisor of $n$, then $b=n/a$ is also a positive divisor of $n$ which implies that one of them is $\leq\sqrt{n}$.

So the required limit exists and it is equal to...